# Displaying Tags for the Page I'm On?

Tags: theme-development, themes, tags

I currently have `<?php $comma = array( 'separator'=> ", " ); wp_tag_cloud($comma); ?>` and I thought this was solved, until going to other posts and seeing the same exact tags.. so I'm guessing this is displaying every tag possible.  How do I only display the tags related to each post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`<?php the_tags(); ?>`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) in the Wordpress loop to display all tags for current post. The default separator is `,`